# Removing license

Tags: visual-studio

I'm nearing the end of my master's thesis, which was done in collaboration with a local company. I used their computers during the work, but they could not provide me with a Visual Studio licence, thus I used my own MSDN Academic Alliance licence. Now that I'm leaving the company, I need to remove the licence. Does a uninstallation completly remove the licence? Is there a way of just removing the licence without uninstallation?

It's Visual Studio 2010 Professional edition, installed on a Windows XP computer.

Comment: (offtopic) So you got VS2010 with MSDNAA? We can only get 2008!

Comment: (still offtopic)One of your Professors needs to manage your licences and can decide what to include in your MSDNAA. If they don't manually activate new available licences, these may not be visible to you. Ask your Prof if s/he could check if VS2010 is available.

Comment: @Bojan and SvenS: What? I'm not asking how to get it from MSDNAA, nor if I can reuse the key. I've been using it for my thesis, and now I need to remove it, since I can't allow the company to keep using it.

Comment: I know i know, well take a look at my answer, i think that if you uninstall it that will do the job. Or ask support (you can see it on MSDNAA)

Comment: Hm, ok, maybe I misunderstood your answer. I thought you meant I could not reuse the key, which I was aware of. Thanks, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

**MSDNAA FAQ:**

> **Q:** Does the license (or "key") permanently unlock the software?
>
> **A:** No - the key allows you to install the software once. If you need to re-install the software, you will need to contact the PA (Program Administrator) at your school. Your PA's contact email information can be found in the support page. To view this information, please click on the Support button above.